# The client lost connection to lab X Matlab

Tags: matlab, parfor

I need help on how to tackle the Matlab error below. After a couple of successful runs I got the error message below in Matlab using parfor.

Opened 2 pools. Send function1 to worker1 and send function2 to worker2. Both functions does some sort of calcs on matrices and generate CSV at the end. It was fine until after a few runs.

> The session that parfor is using has shut down
>
> The client lost connection to lab 2. This might be due to network
>   problems, or the interactive matlabpool job might have errored.

We're using VM machine with a processor Intel Xeon X7560 @2.27GHz (4 processors). The RAM is 16GB. 64-bit OS.

Comment: That error means a worker process crashed. What were you doing at the time?

Comment: I have two functions. Open 2 pools. Send function1 to worker1 and sent function2 to worker2. Both functions does some sort of calcs on matrices and generate CSV at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of a batch run. To resolve the issue instead of re-using the pools for every batch iteration. Make sure to "close" it. Then open fresh Matlab pools for every iteration. Seems to be more stable now, although a lot slower than the previous implementation.